# Powershell script doesn't build WiX installer

Tags: powershell, msbuild, wix, nant

I've got PowerShell scripts that build 3 differents installers.
Two of these are build successfully, but the third one not. Scripts creates 'bin/Release' folders (if not exist) but the .msi file of thrd installer is missing.
As you can see in the log below there are no errors and the message `BUILD SUCCEEDED` is printed out by the compiler.

```
CreateNCPluginInstaller:

 [nant] C:\..\build\NantBuilds\CreateNCPluginInstaller.build 
        Buildfile: file:///C:/../build/NantBuilds/CreateNCPluginInstaller.build
        Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1
        Base Directory: C:\_..\.
        Target(s) specified: createInstallerForNCPlugin 

        Build sequence for target `createInstallerForNCPlugin' is createInstallerForNCPlugin
        Complete build sequence is createInstallerForNCPlugin

        createInstallerForNCPlugin:

             [echo] Create N C Plugin Installer
            [sleep] Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds.
             [exec] Starting 'powershell ("C:\..\build\CreateInstallerForNCPlugin.ps1 Release")' in 'C:\..\'
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:34
             [exec] --> Start compiling project
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:34
             [exec] --> C:\..\scr\Installers\Plugins\E.N.C.Setup\E.N.C.Setup.wixproj
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:34
             [exec] --> C:\..\E.sln
             [exec] True
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:43
             [exec] --> End compiling project
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:43
             [exec] --> Start copying outputs project
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:43
             [exec] --> Copying files from C:\..\scr\Installers\Plugins\E.N.C.Setup\bin\Release\* to C:\_..\installers
             [exec] --> 09/14/2016 14:48:43
             [exec] --> End copying outputs project

        BUILD SUCCEEDED

        Total time: 11.8 seconds.
```

The output of the other 2 installers is exactly the same.

Scripts run, in sequence are these (I use NAnt too):

```
<project name="E" default="createNCPluginInstaller" basedir="..\..\">
<description>Create N C Plugin Installer Build Configuration</description>

<target name="createNCPluginInstaller" description="Creates N C Installer">
<echo message="Create N C Plugin Installer" />
<sleep milliseconds="2000" />
    <exec program="powershell" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${src}build\CreateInstallerForNCPlugin.ps1 ${build-configuration}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

```cs
ExecuteInstaller $eSolution $eNWebSetupProject 'E.N.C.Setup' 'wixproj' $buildConfiguration $outputDirectory

function ExecuteInstaller([string] $solutionPath, [String] $projectPath, 
     [String] $projectName, [String] $projectType, [String] $buildOption, [string] $outputDirectory)
{

PrintToOutputMessage "Start compiling project"

    $project = $projectPath + '\' + $projectName + '.' + $projectType

    PrintToOutputMessage $project

    PrintToOutputMessage $solutionPath

    $ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $ps.StartInfo.Filename = $devenvPath
    $ps.StartInfo.Arguments = " ""$solutionPath"" /Build ""$buildOption"" /project ""$project"" "
    $ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $True
    $ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $ps.start()
    $ps.WaitForExit()
    [string] $Out = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    $from = $projectPath + '\bin\' + $buildOption + '\*'

    PrintToOutputMessage "End compiling project"

    PrintToOutputMessage "Start copying outputs project"

    CopyItemsWithSameExtensions $from $outputDirectory "*.msi"

    PrintToOutputMessage "End copying outputs project"
}
```

I checked all paths generates by the scripts are correct, and the build settings of each project too.

I have no idea what happens and what I can still check, any suggestion would be appreciated. I can provide more details if asked.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just simplify your process, break it into smaller pieces and try each of them separately? Your setup seems overly complicated, why do you need Nant with Powershell? It seems you are compiling your installers using Visual Studio. Why don't use MSBuild?

Comment: Because these scripts must run on TeamCity server. They move some DLLs and then have to build installer.
I do not use MSBuild TeamCity process to build installer because seems that Heat doesn't like relative path. In fact, it replaces "$(SolutionDir)src/../bin" with this error message: "*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*/src/../bin"